# Changing laucher Icons and setting full permission for a file

Tags: android, file, icons, file-permissions, launcher

I have created an application which will allow the user to set different themes for the ICS android device.

After applying the theme, the launcher icons should change from the default icons to the theme icons.

For that i am saving the theme resources(Application icons) to the temporary folder and refreshing the launcher.

In IconCache.java (Where the icons are assigning for the applications) I am checking the current theme. If it is not the 'default theme', then i am getting the icons from the temporary folder which created while applying the theme and assigning it to the applications. If the theme does not have the icon for a particular application, then it will assign the default icon.

The problem which i am facing is some of the application icons are not updating and it is not fixed for a particular application also. Some times it wont update the Mms application. Some times it wont update phone. Sometimes it wont update the browser etc. In some case it will update all the icons and in some cases it will update none.

So i have printed the permission of the Icon files in the assigning area. I found that if the application is not updating with the theme icons then those icon files does not have the read/write/execute permission. But the Icon files are exist in the temporary folder. The changing Icons are having these permissions.

So i try to add the permission for the each files stored in the temporary folder by using

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 " + iconFile); //iconFile = /data/data/com.mytheme/message.jpg
```

It does not worked so i tried with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su chmod 777 " + iconFile);`

This is also not worked. I tried with `iconFile.setWritable(true) iconFile.setReadable(true) iconFile.setExecutable(true)` then also the permission of the Iconfile has not changed.

I dont have any other method to change the permission of the file.

Comment: Where is the `iconFile` located? Internal memory, or SD card?

Comment: It is located in internal memory